# Is there a way to hotkey unarmed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am making an unarmed Khajiit called Punchy.  I'm planning to give him the fists of steel perk and as high of an unarmed damage enchantment as I can get for my gloves.  However, it is annoying that I can't figure out a way to add unarmed to my hotkey (i.e. put away all my weapons and spells and fight with my fists).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do this is to put a weapon on a hot-key, and the press this key twice. It will equip then un-equip the weapon, you'll then fight with your fist. Do the same thing with a shield, and both your hands will be empty.

Comment: Or, alternatively, one 2-handed weapon, which will free both hands when its unequipped.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think the game remember what was equipped in the second hand when using 2 handed weapons or a bow, and keep it equipped.

Comment: @Jupotter that's correct, it won't unequip the offhand, so I can't go dual unarmed.  Your method is what I'm doing right now, but its a huge hassle, I was wondering if there was a way to do it with 1 key rather than having to hit 4 keys.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to help, but i have the xbox version, was scrolling through unarmed posts, I might have a couple suggestions, one being that if you can hot key a 2 handed weapon that would reduce your key clicks to 2, or possibly an in-game macro function(if there isn't one you could try finding an addon) or i believe you can get a free program to create a macro on your keyboard(i have a razer nostromo keypad that allows me to make macros for the keys on it).